# spin jquery ui spinner from array values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, spinner

Have anyone tried to use jQUery UI Spinner that uses array as its source data? Basically what I really want to achieve is I have a list of data (in array with string values), I want my spinner to just spin only with those array values. Hope someone could show me how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I think I'm going to answer my own question, just for the sake for other people who might have the same issue.

```
var dlist = ['banana','papaya','apple']
$( ".spinner" ).spinner({ 
    min: 0,
    max: 2,
    create: function(){
        $(this).parent().append('<input class="spinner-text" value="'+dlist[$(this).val()]+'">');
    },
    stop: function(event,ui) {    
        $(this).siblings('.spinner-text').val(dlist[$(this).val()]);
    }
 });
```

You can see how I did it in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sunnyjaysabuero90/572f6eer/)

Comment: What are the javascript libraries you refer