# JqueryUi Spinner Custom steps

Tags: jquery-ui

I am looking to make the jqueryUI spinner increment by a set of custom values on a list.

For example, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000

Is this possible?

The closest thing I can get it doing is stepping by a set amount.

Maybe it can be done by manually changing the value on the .spin call?

Any help on this would be great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code,

```
var dlist = ['100','250','500', '1000']
$( ".spinner" ).spinner({ 
    min: 0,
    max: 3,
    create: function(){
        $(this).parent().append('<input class="spinner-text" value="'+dlist[$(this).val()]+'">');
    },
    stop: function(event,ui) {    
        $(this).siblings('.spinner-text').val(dlist[$(this).val()]);
    }
 });
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25982122/2567813)

Note: if your array contains 4 values, set max as 3. because first value is already set by default.

see the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/572f6eer/1/)